# How to reassign scope variable without using function

Tags: html, json, angularjs

I was trying to include pagination on a page, it seems working but there is a problem in the code that I need help with.

In my controller I have a scope variable that I used in querying. Factory returned data (used in my ng-repeat) and this same scope variable I needs to assign empty array ([]) to it so that I can use it in my pagination tag. I can I do that in AngularJs?

**Ex:**

```
$scope.datalist = roll.query; //the same datalist(in ng-repeat) I want to reassign it that is;
$scope.datalist = []; //to be used as total-item in pagination
```

**Controller**

```
function($scope, rolls, $window, $http) {
    $scope.datalist = rolls.query(); // return list of rolls
    //paging
    $scope.form = {};
    $scope.datalist = []; //Here is my problem - it make ng-repeat return no data
    $scope.pageSize = 10;
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="tests in datalist | startFrom:(currentPage - 1) * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize >
  <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
  <td>{{datalist.name}}</td>
</tr>

<pagination total-item="datalist.length" ng-model="currentPage" 
            item-per-page="pageSize">
</pagination>
```

When I run my code the `$scope.datalist=[];` make my ng-repeat to display nothing, but when I comment out that line of code the application display the first 10 items only. I need to parse my data into `total-item` in pagination tag, please make `datalist.length` work?

Cheers

Comment: Not understanding why you are resetting your data to an empty array?

Comment: Are you trying to transform your factory data to an array? What does your ‘rolls’ factory look like?

Comment: No, there was a way of re-initializing the factory data variable to empty array which would the holds the page data length in pagination. https://embed.plnkr.co/JiWq3jYorvLZNq9rP8bn/ , see what this guy did in line 4 and 21

Comment: That example doesn't show what you say it shows. That example shows an empty array to initialize the $scope variable. Then he uses the factory to retrieve the data and populate the array. You are doing it backwards, which is resetting your data. You can't use your data after you set to an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy your data list length to another variable before parsing it like below:-

```
function($scope, rolls, $window, $http) {
  $scope.datalist = rolls.query(); // return list of rolls
  //paging
  $scope.form = {};
  $scope.datalistLength = angular.copy($scope.datalist.length); //Here is my problem - it 
  make ng-repeat return no data
  $scope.pageSize = 10;
  $scope.currentPage = 1;
}
```

Now use this variable into your pagination tags like below:-

```
<pagination total-item="datalistLength" ng-model="currentPage" item-per-page="pageSize"></pagination>
```

Comment: Hi, I don't want to copy my data, what I want is how to have my datalist variabe initialized to empty array  $scope.datalist = []; this will hold the number of page items in pagination, using datalist.length. Can $scope.$watch work?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly when you run `$scope.datalist = []`, it would return no data. So you must set `$scope.datalist` what you want to display. Secondly, `when I comment out that line of code the application display the first 10 items only` this is happen maybe because of the code `limitTo: pageSize` works.